# Check Internet on resuming an activity

Tags: android

I have an android application,which uses internet. If internet is unavailable,I disable all the buttons in the activity. But when I resume my activity after enabling the Internet,Buttons are still disabled.
Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the availability of network in `onResume`. I assume that you have given 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` permission in your manifest file. I have give my tested code below that give you the availability status of internet()_

```
/**
 * Check whether Internet Connection is available or not(e.g., connected or
 * Disconnected)
 * 
 * @param context
 *            : Context of current Class
 * @return Boolean: true if connected false otherwise.
 */
public static final boolean isNetWork(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    /** to get info of WIFI N/W : */
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = conMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    /** to get info of mobile N/W : */
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = conMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if ((wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.isConnected())
            || (mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.isConnected())) {
        Log.i("Is Net work?", "isNetWork:in 'isNetWork_if' is N/W Connected:"
                + NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
        return true;
    } else if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and when you goes in `onResume` check network availability_

```
/*In your on resume check I/N*/
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    if (isNetWork(your_activity_name.this)) {
        //Your Code...
        yourButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        //Your Code...
        yourButton.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you check the Internet every time you resume your activity? It would be great to see some code by the way.

Comment: Yes. But I have sorted it now.It is done simply by overriding onResume() method in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use onStop(), onResume() or the methods from the lifecycle that you may need, you should hide the buttons on destructive methods... That way each time the user reenters the activity, you can check the connection